googlecompute: Error waiting for SSH: Packer experienced an authentication error when trying to connect via SSH
I am  moving our default GCP runner image to a newer version of Ubuntu (22.04) based Golden Image.For this, I am using packer v1.10.2
I faced this error while building new runner image:
==> googlecompute: Error waiting for SSH: Packer experienced an authentication error when trying to connect via SSH. This can happen if your username/password are wrong. You may want to double-check your credentials as part of your debugging process. original error: ssh: handshake failed: ssh: unable to authenticate, attempted methods [none publickey], no supported methods remain
this is packer.json file:
{
    "variables": {
        "account_file": "credentials.json",
        "gcp_project": "{{ env `PROJECT` }}",
        "gcp_zone": "{{ env `REGION` }}-c",
        "gcp_network": "{{ env `GCP_NETWORK` }}",
        "gcp_subnet": "{{ env `GCP_SUBNET` }}",
        "gcp_network_tag": "{{ env `GCP_NETWORK_TAG` }}",
        "disk_type": "{{ env `DISK_TYPE` }}",
        "template_suffix": "{{ env `TEMPLATE_SUFFIX` }}",
        "image_template_name": "{{ env `IMAGE_TEMPLATE_NAME` }}",
        "image_timestamp": "{{ isotime `20060102150405` }}",
        "image_description": "{{ env `IMAGE_DESCRIPTION` }}",
        "image_basename": "{{ env `IMAGE_BASENAME` }}",
        "image_os_name": "{{ env `IMAGE_OS_NAME` }}",
        "image_family": "{{ env `IMAGE_FAMILY` }}",
        "image_name_suffix": "{{ env `IMAGE_NAME_SUFFIX` }}",
        "image_name": "{{ user `image_basename` }}-{{ user `image_timestamp` }}{{ user `image_name_suffix` }}",
        "source_image": "{{ env `SOURCE_IMAGE` }}",
        "source_image_project_id": "{{ env `SOURCE_IMAGE_PROJECT_ID` }}",
        "cc_range_list": "{{ env `CC_RANGE_LIST` }}",
        "pre_release": "{{ env `PRE_RELEASE` }}",
        "git_commit": "{{ env `GIT_COMMIT` }}"
    },
    "builders": [
        {
            "type": "googlecompute",
            "project_id": "{{ user `gcp_project` }}",
            "zone": "{{ user `gcp_zone` }}",
            "disk_type": "{{ user `disk_type` }}",
            "source_image": "{{ user `source_image` }}",
            "source_image_project_id": "{{ user `source_image_project_id` }}",
            "account_file": "{{ user `account_file` }}",
            "ssh_username": "gcloud",
            "image_family": "{{ user `image_family` }}",
            "image_name": "{{ user `image_name` }}",
            "image_description": "{{ user `image_description` }}",
            "image_storage_locations": ["eu"],
            "image_labels": {
                "timestamp": "{{ user `image_timestamp` }}",
                "prerelease": "{{ user `pre_release` }}",
                "gitcommit": "{{ user `git_commit` }}"
            },
            "network": "solinas-vpc",
            "subnetwork": "solinas-sugar",
            "omit_external_ip": false,
            "use_internal_ip": true,
            "tags": ["{{ user `gcp_network_tag` }}"]
        }
    ],
    "provisioners": [
        {
            "type": "file",
            "source": "init-common.sh",
            "destination": "/tmp/init-common.sh"
        },
        {
            "type": "shell",
            "execute_command": "chmod +x {{ .Path }}; sudo sh -c '{{ .Vars }} {{ .Path }} {{ user `image_os_name`}}-{{ user `image_timestamp`}}{{ user `image_name_suffix`}} \"{{ user `cc_range_list`}}\"'",
            "script": "runnerinit-{{ user `image_template_name` }}.sh"
        }
    ],
    "post-processors": [
        {
            "output": "manifest.json",
            "strip_path": true,
            "type": "manifest",
            "custom_data": {
                "image_timestamp": "{{ user `image_timestamp` }}",
                "image_name": "{{ user `image_name` }}"
            }
        }
    ]
}

on the Gcloud shell for this VM runner i executed this command:
gcloud compute ssh --zone "europe-west3-c" "packer-6613dc1f-06fd-6784-d9fe-4e22cdbde626" --      project "sap-solinas-dev" --ssh-key-file /path/to/private/key
ssh: connect to host 35.242.235.89 port 22: Connection timed out
ERROR: (gcloud.compute.ssh) [/usr/bin/ssh] exited with return code [255].
